# positive lookbehind not behaving correctly

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

The code snippet for positive lookbehind is below

```
public class PositiveLookBehind {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "[a-z](?<=9)";
        String input = "a9es m9x us9s w9es";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        System.out.println("===starting====");
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found:"+matcher.group()
            +" start index:"+matcher.start()
            +" end index is "+matcher.end()); 
        }
        System.out.println("===ending=====");
    }
}
```

I was expecting that I should have 4 matches but to my surprise the output shows no match.

Can anyone point out my mistake?

As far as my understanding goes the regex here is alphabet preceded by digit 9 which is satisfied in 4 locations.

Comment: for alphabet preceded by digit 9, change regex to `(?<=9)[a-z]` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pMTrDe/1)

Comment: @Matt.G appreciate your quick response. iam learning regex and get very confused in these lookarouds. Can you point to any online resource which shows how the regex engine operates. and why my understanding of lookbehind was wrong

Comment: wrong: match one letter (a-z) and look behind (not ahead) for an 9, that is, if the previous found **letter** is 9 (after a letter is matched, the *pointer* is after that letter and look behind will look before the *pointer*, that is, what was already matched)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Notice that `(?<=9)` is placed *after* `[a-z]`. What it means?

Lets consider data like `"a9c"`.

At start regex-engine places its "cursor" at start of the string which it iterates, here:

```
|a9c
^-regex cursor is here
```

Then regex-engine is trying to match each part of regex-pattern ***from left to right***. So in case of `[a-z](?<=9)` it first will try to find match for `[a-z]` and after successfully finding that match for it, it will try to move to evaluation of `(?<=9)` part.

So match for `[a-z]` will happen here:

```
a9c
*<-- match for `[a-z]`
```

After that match regex will move cursor here:

a|9c
   *^--- regex-engine cursor
   ^---- match for `[a-z]`

So now `(?<=9)` will be evaluated (notice position of cursor `|`). `(?<=subregex)` checks if immediately before cursor exist text which can be matched by `subregex`. But here since cursor is directly after `a` `(?<=9)` look-behind "sees"/includes that `a` as data which subexpression should test. But since `a` can't be matched by `9` evaluation fails.

#### Solution(s)

You probably wanted to check if `9` is placed *before* acceptable letter. To achieve that you can modify your regex in many ways:

- with `[a-z](?<=9.)` you make look-behind test *two* previous characters

  ```
  a9c|
   ^^
   9. - `9` matches 9, `.` matches any character (one directly before cursor)
  ```
- or simpler `(?<=9)[a-z]` to first look for `9` and then look for `[a-z]` which will let regex match `9c` if cursor will be at `9|c`.

Comment: For more info about lookaround mechanisms visit: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

Your cuurent pattern: `[a-z](<=9)` means: match lowercase letter and assure, that *position* right after the letter is preceeded by `9`, which is contradiciton.

If you want to match letter preceeded by `9` use: `(<=9)[a-z]`, which now means: assure what preceeds is `9`, if so, match lowercase letter.

Comment: your answer helped me a lot. i thought cursor is not moving after matching [a-z].....